# Carregar header e footer com .load() e torná-lo visível para o Google

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google, seo

Estou montando um site em HTML puro, que tem a seguinte estrutura

[image: site structure]

Considerando que eu não tenho uma Master Page como no ASP.NET, eu preciso replicar o header e o footer para outras páginas usando a função `.load()` do jQuery, desta forma:

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
</div>

<div class="content">
<span>Content goes here!</span>
</div>

<div class="footer">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".header").load("header.html");
$(".footer").load("footer.html");
```

Meu problema é: quando eu uso a ferramenta [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) para analisar meu site, os conteúdos do header e do footer não são considerados.

Eu já li a respeito de:

[Pushstate e carregamento de conteúdo via AJAX em links](https://moz.com/blog/create-crawlable-link-friendly-ajax-websites-using-pushstate) mas isto não é uma boa ideia pra mim, considerando que o conteúdo replicado não é ativado por um link, e sim quando a página carrega.

[Making AJAX Applications Crawleable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?csw=1) mas este artigo está descontinuado.

Estou iniciando com SEO e coisas do tipo, portanto não tenho ideia de como carregar conteudo assíncronamente e fazer com que o Google o encontre.

Obrigado!

Comment: Acredito que como você está carregando via JS, isto irá ser complicado mesmo. Qual linguagem você está utilizando?

Comment: Olá @Jhonathan! Estou utilizando somente HTML puro, e JS.